# Can you enchant yourself with an aura that enchants a permanent?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm relatively new to MTG so maybe I'm way off, but I can't find any conclusive answers nor official rulings on the following:

If one can enchant a permanent,
and a planeswalker is considered a permanent,
and the player is considered a planeswalker...

Can you enchant yourself? It sounds ridiculously overpowered (you could do such insane things as turn yourself into an indestructible artifact) but I can't find any real reason you wouldn't be able to

Comment: What do you think turning yourself into an indestructible artifact would do? Even if you could do that, it wouldn't do anything beneficial.

Comment: It was just an example, but one could argue it could make you immune to something like Door To Nothingness. Or imagine casting hexproof on yourself. If such things were possible you could definitely play some interesting moves.

Comment: It's important to note that keywords have specific meanings though. For example, "Indestructible" would not prevent game loss. It specifically means "A permanent with indestructible can’t be destroyed" and nothing else. "Destroyed" also has a specific meaning, and losing a game is not being "destroyed". Magic is full of very specific terms like this, so it's important to not think about 2 things as basically the same just because they have similar meanings in English.

Comment: Oh, and you can give yourself Hexproof with several different cards. :) [See here](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=+%5B%22you%20have%20hexproof%22%5D%7C%7Ctext=+%5B%22you%20have%20hexproof%22%5D)

Comment: Imagine becoming tapped, and having to play lying sideways on your chair.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**The player is a "planeswalker" only in lore terms. As far as game mechanics are concerned, "planeswalker" has a defined meaning, and a player is not a planeswalker.**

A planeswalker in the mechanical sense is a type of *object*, a game entity that interacts with players and other objects:

> 102.1. A player is one of the people in the game. [..]
>
> 109.1. An object is an ability on the stack, a card, a copy of a card, a token, a spell, a permanent, or an emblem.
>
> 110.4. There are five permanent types: artifact, creature, enchantment, land, and planeswalker.

So when an aura can enchant a (type of) permanent, then that does not include players, and vice versa. There are auras that can enchant players, but the aura will always say so specifically. Here are [all auras that can enchant players](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=+%5B%22enchant%20player%22%5D), and here are [all auras that can enchant planeswalkers](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=+%5B%22enchant%20permanent%22%5D).

Comment: Makes sense, it seemed fairly gamebreaking to me that the physical players themselves appeared to have no real distinction from other aspects of the game.

Answer (score 5):

Players are not planeswalkers, nor are they permanents, so the examples you provide don't work.  The player as a planewalker was a flavor-only description, but it has no truth within gameplay.

There are some specific enchantments that ["Enchant Player"](https://scryfall.com/search?q=oracle%3A%2Fenchant%20player%2F&unique=cards&as=grid&order=name) (many have the subtype Curse).  You can enchant yourself with these auras, but you probably wouldn't want to for many of them.